# Poisson Approximation to calculate the probability that at most 2 persons in 500 will have a birthday on Christmas

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

This is from Hoel's Probability book. Use the Poisson Approximation to calculate the probability that at most 2 persons in  500 will have a birthday on Christmas. Assume 365 days in the year.
On average $\frac{500}{365}=1.36$ of people have a birtday every day.
This is what I've got at the moment:
$$ P\left(X\leq2\right)=\sum_{x=0}^{2}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{x}}{x!}=f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)$$

$$P\left(X\leq2\right)=0.2566+0.3490+0.1186=0.7242$$

Comment: This question is about how the poisson relates to the binomial distribution.

Comment: Perhaps too much rounding too soon. $500/365
= 1.369863.$

Answer (score 1):

Following @DanielAdams' Comment:

Binomial probability: $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=500, p=1/365),$  This is exact assuming independence and
365 equally likely birthdays.

Find $P(X \le 2) = 0.8317.$ [Computation in R.]

```
pbinom(2, 500, 1/355)
[1] 0.8316545
```

Poisson probability: $ Y \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 500/365).$ This is an approximation.

Find $P(Y \le 2) = 0.8407.$

```
ppois(2, 500/365)
[1] 0.8407328
```

The three Poisson probabilities summed are as follows:

```
dpois(0:2, 500/365)
[1] 0.2541418 0.3481394 0.2384517
```

*Note:* In R `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, `ppois` is a Poisson CDF, and `dpois` is a Poisson PDF.